# Get reservation/menu URL from Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I am looking for an automated way to get a place's reservation/menu URL to use in my service. However, I am having a hard time finding this in their docs. Is this not possible via the Google Places API? If so, is there an alternative I could use?

Comment: There's a [`formatted_phone_number`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResponses) on the response of a place details request which can be used for booking. But for the menu, I don't think there's a feature for that in Places API.

Comment: I was mentioning a reservation URL, not the phone number. Google shows it on a place's page, so I was expecting to see it in their API as well.

Comment: Oh, I think it is available on Google Business. I saw this [article](https://www.leadmonk.io/post/how-to-add-an-appointment-booking-link-to-your-google-business-profile). You should check it out. But I believe this feature is only available for the business owners themselves. And regarding what you saw on Google Maps App, please set your expectation that Google Maps Platform and the Google Maps App are different and that their features/functionalities differ in some way.

Comment: I can see [reservable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#Place-reservable) attribute on the docs but it only returns boolean. You could try filing a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309) on the Issue Tracker if you want.

Comment: I was afraid of that. `reservable` I feel is for their own reservation's platform, not for anything external a place may fill in. Too bad this is not available in their API...

Comment: You should try filing a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309) on the Issue Tracker.